# How to declare an empty char* and increase the size dynamically?

Tags: c++, c, char, dynamic-memory-allocation, strcmp

Let's say I am trying to do the following (this is a sub problem of what I am trying to achieve):

```
int compareFirstWord(char* sentence, char* compareWord){
      char* temp; int i=-1;
      while(*(sentence+(++i))!=' ') { *(temp+i) = *(sentence+i); }
      return strcmp(temp, compareWord); }
```

When I ran `compareFirstWord("Hi There", "Hi");`, I got error at the copy line. It said I was using temp uninitialized. Then I used `char* temp = new char[];` In this case the function returned 1 and not 0. When I debugged, I saw temp starting with some random characters of length 16 and `strcmp` fails because of this.

Is there a way to declare an empty char* and increase the size dynamically only to length and contents of what I need ? Any way to make the function work ? I don't want to use `std::string`.

Comment: Use `std::string`.

Comment: Use `std::vector` then.

Comment: Why don't you want to use `std::string`? If you actually **can't** use it fair enough, but if you **can** use it and just don't want to, i think you should, you can add a character to the string with `str.push_back(a_char)` you can reserve space for the string with `str.reserve(size)` and check the allocated space with `str.capacity()` and then `str.shrink_to_fit()` reduces the strings capacity to fit the actual `str.size()` which can be set/reset with `str.resize(size)`, if you need the `char *` equivalent of a string you can just call `str.c_str()` and clear the string with `str.clear()`

Comment: Thanks for a very clear explanation!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C, you may do:

```
int compareFirstWord(const char* sentence, const char* compareWord)
{
    while (*compareWord != '\0' && *sentence == *compareWord) {
        ++sentence;
        ++compareWord;
    }
    if (*compareWord == '\0' && (*sentence == '\0' || *sentence == ' ')) {
        return 0;
    }
    return *sentence < *compareWord ? -1 : 1;
}
```

With `std::string`, you just have:

```
int compareFirstWord(const std::string& sentence, const std::string& compareWord)
{
    return sentence.compare(0, sentence.find(" "), compareWord);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

temp is an uninitialized variable.

It looks like you are attempting to extract the first word out of the sentence in your loop.

In order to do it this way, you would first have to initialize temp to be at least as long as your sentence.

Also, your sentence may not have a space in it.  (What about period, \t, \r, \n? Do these matter?)

In addition, you must terminate temp with a null character.

You could try:

```
int len = strlen(sentence);
char* temp = new char[len + 1];
int i = 0;

while(i < len && *(sentence+(i))!=' ') {
   *(temp+i) = *(sentence+i); 
   i++;
}
*(temp+i) = '\0';
int comparable = strcmp(temp, compareWord);
delete temp;
return comparable;
```

Also consider using isspace(*(sentence+(i))), which will at least catch all whitespace.
In general, however, I'd use a library, or STL...  Why reinvent the wheel...

Comment: After initializing the temp, you could also use strcpy, followed by setting the first whitespace with '\0'

Comment: Depending on whether you trust the source of your sentences, be aware that they may not be in correct form, with a null terminator.  This could lead to buffer overflow or other issues. strlen, for example, requires null terminated strings, I believe.

Comment: BTW, you have a memory leak.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I forgot, remember to delete temp at the end of the function, before return.

Comment: `[]` are missing after `delete`, it should be `delete [] temp;`

Comment: Thanks @jazeee, not ending with '\0' was the main mistake.

Comment: Sorry – this is a **terrible** answer. Do not *ever* use this in real code. It’s error-prone. The only thing redeeming this answer is the last sentence, but I’m prepared t bet that OP is ignoring that.

Comment: I tend to agree that the code isn't great, actually.  I was trying to keep in the style of the OP.